# Float rounding off error

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

```
#include<iostream>

long myround(float f)
{
  if (f >= UINT_MAX) return f;
  return f + 0.5f;
}

int main()
{
  f = 8388609.0f;
  std:cout.precision(16);
  std::cout << myround(f) << std::endl;
}
```

Output: 8388610.0

I'm trying to make sense of the output. The next floating number larger than 
8388609.0 is 8388610 But why the rounded value is not 8388609?

Comment: _"The next floating number larger than 8388609.0 is 8388610"_ How did you arrive at this conclusion?

Comment: Single-precision floats don't have enough space to guarantee representation of all these decimal digits (more than six). What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: This code doesn't compile. You do not have a declaration of `f`. Post your _actual_ [MCVE] that led to the stated output.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit All integers up to 2^24 can be exactly represented as single-precision floating point, and above 2^23, all single-precision floating point numbers are integers.

Comment: @Sneftel: Integers, yes.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ...yes? Not sure what point you're making. The fact that the next `float` after 8388609 is 8388610 directly follows from those properties, as does the fact that all seven-digit integers are representable as `float`s.

Comment: @Sneftel: I'm not making any "point", I'm trying to persuade the OP to give their working and reasoning, to make this a good question.

Comment: You cannot have a language tag and the "language-agnostic" tag together for a question. That does not make sense. As your question is specific to the implementation of your C++ program, it is not language-agnostic - removed the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IEEE-754 defines several possible rounding modes, but in practice, the one almost always used is "round to nearest, ties to even". This is also known as "Banker's rounding", for no reason anybody can discern.

"Ties to even" means that if the to-be-rounded result of a floating point computation is precisely halfway between two representable numbers, the rounding will be in whichever direction makes the LSB of the result zero. In your case, 8388609.5 is halfway between 8388609 and 8388610, but only the latter has a zero in the last bit, so the rounding is upwards. If you had passed in 8388610.0 instead, the result would be rounded downwards; if you had passed in 8388611.0, it would be rounded upwards.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Answers my question. Also, I assume the floating point hardware makes this decision of how the rounding must be done. Does this mean that the FP hardware actually computes the precise value and maps to the representable floating point representation based on a rounding policy?

Comment: This answered my question about FP hardware.
http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~markhill/cs354/Fall2008/notes/flpt.apprec.html

Answer (score 1):

If you change your example to use `double` then the error disappears. The problem is `float` is more limited than `double` in the number of significant digits it can store. Adding 0.5 to your value simply exceeds the precision limits for a float, causing it to preform some rounding. In this case, `8388609.0f + 0.5f == 8388610.0f`.

```
#include<iostream>

long myround(double f)
{
    if (f >= UINT_MAX) return f;
    return f + 0.5;
}

int main()
{
    double f = 8388609.0;
    std::cout.precision(16);
    std::cout << myround(f) << std::endl;
}
```

If you continue to add digits to your number, it will also eventually fail for `double`.

Edit:
You can test this easily with a `static_assert`. This compiles on my platform `static_assert(8388609.0f + 0.5f == 8388610.0f, "");`. It will likely compile on yours.